# Resetting phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, passwords, phpmyadmin, account

I'm running version 3.3.9, and I'm having trouble with trying to restore my admin password, as well as reset the root password.  I get the following popup when logging onto **localhost/xampp/phpMyAdmin** through the address bar:
[image: PHPmyadmin login]

What should I do in order to reset my password of the root?

N.B. I've already tried setting the password via the `config.inc` folder, and nothing changed.

Comment: try with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124447/reset-root-password-with-wrong-mysql-config and remember after changing the password to revert the change in my.ini

Answer (score 1):

Try this from your **command line** :

```
mysqladmin -u root -p 'oldpassword' password newpass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqladmin -u root -p 'oldpassword' password newpass
```

I think this code should work implement it through the script tags of your index.php file so the xammp database will recognise the code!