# Cannot log into xampp

Tags: xampp

Is there a way to find your old user name and password for xampp if you have lost it? Also, the xampp server says 'xampp user; does that mean that 'xampp user' is the user name?

Alternately, is there a way to rest the username and password, if the originals cannot be recovered?

Answer (score 2):

Old question but here's the answer, as I recently got stuck with this:
go to \xampp\security and delete xamppdirpasswd.txt, then replace the contents of xampp.users with just 'user'. Now refresh on localhost and you should be prompted for username and password where you just need to enter 'user' and no password.
Then go to http://[localhost]/security/xamppsecurity.php and set a new one!

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way is to manually set new password and/or username.
There is a post on Stacowerflow already which explains quite well how to do it:

- Go to your xampp\mysql\bin\ folder
- Edit my.ini and insert skip-grant-tables below [mysqld]
- Restart MySQL
- Set new password for your root user by running UPDATE mysql.user SET
- Password=PASSWORD('new_password') WHERE User='root' in phpMyAdmin in
  the mysql database (or just leave it like this if MySQL cannot be
  accessed from remote hosts)

[Original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124447/reset-root-password-with-wrong-mysql-config)