# trouble with entering my phpmyadmin from xamp

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I put the password and root user (root and press enter).. then the phpmyadmin runs indefinitely..and never reaches inside. Also I would like to remove the authentication screen altogther..how do I do that..

Here is my config.inc.php file:

```
    <?php
/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE SECURE COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;

/* Authentication type and info 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
*/
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma_recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma_table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '8080';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

?>
```

UPDATE:

This is how I approach phpmyadmin:

```
http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/
```

swapping this:
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';

to this:

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';

Didnt work, I still get a long loading time..and nothing appears in the end

**php_error_log**:

```
[22-Nov-2012 08:35:56 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(lang.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\index.php on line 2

[22-Nov-2012 08:46:59 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(lang.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\index.php on line 2

[22-Nov-2012 09:01:38 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpmyadmin\libraries\session.inc.php on line 96
```

error file from **C:\xampp\apache\logs**

```
 [Thu Nov 22 10:56:28.128254 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 992:tid 252] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4152

[Thu Nov 22 10:56:29.065254 2012] [ssl:warn] [pid 4152:tid 264] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Thu Nov 22 10:56:29.098254 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4152:tid 264] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Thu Nov 22 11:15:44.631864 2012] [core:warn] [pid 6036:tid 252] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Thu Nov 22 11:15:44.928894 2012] [ssl:warn] [pid 6036:tid 252] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Thu Nov 22 11:15:44.961897 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6036:tid 252] AH00455: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 22 11:15:44.961897 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6036:tid 252] AH00456: Server built: Aug 18 2012 12:41:37
[Thu Nov 22 11:15:44.961897 2012] [core:notice] [pid 6036:tid 252] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Nov 22 11:15:44.962897 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6036:tid 252] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6056
[Thu Nov 22 11:15:45.790980 2012] [ssl:warn] [pid 6056:tid 264] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Thu Nov 22 11:15:45.823984 2012] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6056:tid 264] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Some of the details from access file in the same folder:

```
    ::1 - - [22/Nov/2012:10:56:32 +0200] "GET /phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin.css.php?server=1&token=437f6c565c1596df2943490f3a782513&js_frame=right&nocache=4043133233 HTTP/1.1" 200 82604 "http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30"
::1 - - [22/Nov/2012:10:56:32 +0200] "GET /phpmyadmin/js/messages.php?lang=en&db=&token=437f6c565c1596df2943490f3a782513 HTTP/1.1" 200 16556 "http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30"
::1 - - [22/Nov/2012:10:56:33 +0200] "GET /phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/img/logo_right.png HTTP/1.1" 200 4548 "http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30"
::1 - - [22/Nov/2012:10:56:33 +0200] "GET /phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/img/input_bg.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 170 "http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30"
::1 - - [22/Nov/2012:10:56:38 +0200] "POST /phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 - "http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30"
::1 - - [22/Nov/2012:11:01:38 +0200] "-" 408 - "-" "-"
::1 - - [22/Nov/2012:10:56:38 +0200] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php?token=437f6c565c1596df2943490f3a782513 HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30"
::1 - - [22/Nov/2012:10:57:54 +0200] "POST /phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 154 "http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30"
::1 - - [22/Nov/2012:11:09:09 +0200] "POST /phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 302 - "http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30"
::1 - - [22/Nov/2012:11:14:09 +0200] "-" 408 - "-" "-"
::1 - - [22/Nov/2012:11:09:09 +0200] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php?token=437f6c565c1596df2943490f3a782513 HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30"
::1 - - [22/Nov/2012:11:20:51 +0200] "-" 408 - "-" "-"
::1 - - [22/Nov/2012:11:15:50 +0200] "POST /phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30"
::1 - - [22/Nov/2012:11:33:05 +0200] "GET /Dummy/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30"
::1 - - [22/Nov/2012:11:33:38 +0200] "GET /Dummy/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 193 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30"
```

Now I get:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpmyadmin\libraries\session.inc.php on line 96
```

Is there a way to disable session completely?

Last Changes:

```
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '8080';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '12345';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

Now I cant even reach the panel :(

Comment: what do you get with `http://127.0.0.1:8080/phpmyadmin/` ..??

Answer (score 2):

Try uncommenting the line below line:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

and change `auth_type` to `config`

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

**EDIT:**
/* Authentication type and info */

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'your_mysql_user_here';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'your_mysql_password_here';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124447/reset-root-password-with-wrong-mysql-config/) you can see find instruction as on how to reset MySQL password in case you had typo etc.

Comment: No..thats what I am getting:http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/index.php..an empty string

Comment: Check your antivirus; firewall... Regardless how you approaching to MySQL server port 8080 is utilized by Apache. MySQL is using it's own port; ensure you have all permission as needed. Your config file seems okay to me.

Comment: I know..but when i connect to mysql through the mysql control panel, it seems to be running well, without throwing any error.. it uses port 3306

Comment: Check mysql_error.log; it should be in mysql folder. What does it say?

Comment: updated answer.. I didnt find mysql_error.log..but error_log in php folder

Comment: I get an error 1045 access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' using password no

Comment: When I do this: mysql --user=root --password=''   I get the same error but with Yes..instead of no

Comment: instead of `mysql --user=root --password=''` you need to type `mysql --user=root --password=""`

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

**and**

```
/* Authentication type and info 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
*/
```

to

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

Additionally, you need the below line also:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
```

Comment: under the lines below, you need to provide the same mysql username and password which lets you login through command prompt `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';`