# How to get back Lost phpMyAdmin Password, XAMPP

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, passwords, xampp

I have a local host running on XAMPP on a Mac. At some point I set a password in phpMyAdmin which I've ow forgotten. Can anyone help me get back into phpMyAdmin? I've followed a ton of tutorials but they all either don't work or refer to some file that doesn't seem to be on my computer. Is there an easy way?

When I try to open:

```
http://localhost
```

I get:

```
The Server http://localhost:80 requires a username and password
```

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124447/reset-root-password-with-wrong-mysql-config

Comment: Thanks RXM unfortunately this is one of the tutorials I already attempted.

Comment: Found this: https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/how-to-change-the-password-for-phpmyadmin.518972/ is it of any help ?

Comment: If you have checked save password to notepad then the text file with password will generated into mysql directory. it can help you.

Answer (score -15, accepted):

Reinstalling the software fixes the issue, just make sure not to delete the htdocs folder in the process.

Comment: How do I make sure I don't loose my databases as well?

Comment: @BenPearce Back up it

Comment: LOL ;) very quick solution ;)

Comment: is this even a solution!

Answer (score 37):

You want to edit this file:
"\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php"

change this line:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'WhateverPassword';
```

to whatever your password is.
If you don't remember your password, then run this command in the Shell:

```
mysqladmin.exe -u root password WhateverPassword
```

where 'WhateverPassword' is your new password.

Comment: sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysqladmin -u root password root
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

Answer (score 15):

There is a batch file called `resetroot.bat` located in the xammp folders 'C:\xampp\mysql' run this and it will delete the `phpmyadmin` passwords. Then all you need to do is start the `MySQL` service in `xamp` and click the admin button.

Answer (score 3):

The question may be getting old, but I've struggled with the same issue just now.

After deleting passwords with `resetroot.bat`, as instructed by [Nedshed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18427124/3835249), you can choose another password by going to `http://localhost/security/index.php`

Answer (score 1):

The best thing is to go to your phpmyadmin folder and open config.inc.php and change allownopassword=false to **$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;**

Answer (score 0):

## The only solution worked for me:

(source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22784404/2377343 )

You need to stop Mysql and change user password using Commands.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this worked for me "/opt/lampp/xampp security" in Centos

[root@XXXXX ~]# /opt/lampp/xampp security

XAMPP:  Quick security check...

XAMPP:  Your XAMPP pages are secured by a password.

XAMPP: Do you want to change the password anyway? [no] yes

XAMPP: Password:

XAMPP: Password (again):

XAMPP:  Password protection active. Please use 'xampp' as user name!

XAMPP:  MySQL is not accessable via network. Good.

XAMPP:  MySQL has a root passwort set. Fine! :)

XAMPP:  The FTP password for user 'daemon' is still set to 'xampp'.

XAMPP: Do you want to change the password? [yes]

XAMPP: Password:

XAMPP: Password (again):

XAMPP: Reload ProFTPD...ok.

XAMPP:  Done.

[root@XXXXX ~]#

Answer (score 0):

**This is what helped me:**

Wherever you have installed XAMPP open PhpMyAdmin Folder,( In my
case C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin).

There you find a file named config.php, open it with notepad or any
editor.

You find user and password for phpMyAdmin like this.

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
**$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

Answer (score -4):

Unless you have changed your password the default setting dont require you to enter a password to connect to the MYSQL server, try:

`mysql_connect('localhost','root','');`

if not then you can export your databases to a external file, just follow these instructions.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-backup.html

if you are unable to access phpMyAdmin then try,

http://www.simplehelp.net/2008/11/26/how-to-reset-a-lost-mysql-root-password/