# How can I change mysql user privileges?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm using XAMPP and the only way I can enter phpMyAdmin is without a Password and with a made up username. I've forgot my real credentials because I hadn't used XAMPP for a while.

If I try to enter with the username: root it doesn't work.

Upon entering phpMyAdmin I have no privileges whatsoever and thus can't even create a new safe user\password combination.

I've tried many things and don't know what else to do. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're technically resetting the password of MySQL, not phpMyAdmin (as phpMyAdmin is just an interface to access MySQL). I don't use XAMPP so don't promise this won't inadvertently break something else along the way (thought I can't imagine what would depend on having the root password), but there are [many](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#i-have-lost-my-mysql-root-password-what-can-i-do) [pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511444/lost-my-phpmyadmin-password-xampp) [with](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/01/how-to-change-the-root-password-for-mysql-in-xampp/) [suggestions](https://www.google.com/#q=reset+mysql+password). If your phpMyAdmin auth_type is config, you'll also need to put the new password in the configuration file; otherwise just type the new password when you log in.

Answer (score 0):

Please open config.inc.php in phpmyadmin folder with your code editor and you can find your username and password there