# probleme Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, lamp

have XAMPP for Linux 5.6.12-0 . When I Start the Xammp , It shows the following :

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.12-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

But when you go to http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/, it says:

```
 Cannot log in to the MySQL server
 Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

My cinfig.inc.php :

```
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * phpMyAdmin sample configuration, you can use it as base for
 * manual configuration. For easier setup you can use setup/
 *
 * All directives are explained in documentation in the doc/ folder
 * or at <http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/>.
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin
 */

/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE SECURE COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'brahim';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
/* Server parameters */
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/*
 * phpMyAdmin configuration storage settings.
 */

/* User used to manipulate with storage */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = '';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlport'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Storage database and tables */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
/* Contrib / Swekey authentication */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_swekey_config'] = '/etc/swekey-pma.conf';

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

/*
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

/**
 * Whether to display icons or text or both icons and text in table row
 * action segment. Value can be either of 'icons', 'text' or 'both'.
 */
//$cfg['RowActionType'] = 'both';

/**
 * Defines whether a user should be displayed a "show all (records)"
 * button in browse mode or not.
 * default = false
 */
//$cfg['ShowAll'] = true;

/**
 * Number of rows displayed when browsing a result set. If the result
 * set contains more rows, "Previous" and "Next".
 * default = 30
 */
//$cfg['MaxRows'] = 50;

/**
 * disallow editing of binary fields
 * valid values are:
 *   false    allow editing
 *   'blob'   allow editing except for BLOB fields
 *   'noblob' disallow editing except for BLOB fields
 *   'all'    disallow editing
 * default = blob
 */
//$cfg['ProtectBinary'] = 'false';

/**
 * Default language to use, if not browser-defined or user-defined
 * (you find all languages in the locale folder)
 * uncomment the desired line:
 * default = 'en'
 */
//$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
//$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'de';

/**
 * How many columns should be used for table display of a database?
 * (a value larger than 1 results in some information being hidden)
 * default = 1
 */
//$cfg['PropertiesNumColumns'] = 2;

/**
 * Set to true if you want DB-based query history.If false, this utilizes
 * JS-routines to display query history (lost by window close)
 *
 * This requires configuration storage enabled, see above.
 * default = false
 */
//$cfg['QueryHistoryDB'] = true;

/**
 * When using DB-based query history, how many entries should be kept?
 *
 * default = 25
 */
//$cfg['QueryHistoryMax'] = 100;

/**
 * Should error reporting be enabled for JavaScript errors
 *
 * default = 'ask'
 */
//$cfg['SendErrorReports'] = 'ask';

/*
 * You can find more configuration options in the documentation
 * in the doc/ folder or at <http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/>.
 */
?>
```

Comment: Is your server supposed to have no password? That would be the first thing I would check.

Comment: I did not understand

Comment: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';` seems strange because it suggests that your SQL server doesn't have a password on it. Is that the case?

Comment: Figuring out the password and properly putting it in the config file would be the first thing I would do if I were you.

Comment: Do you know the password for your server?

Comment: I do not know the password .

Comment: That could make logging in quite difficult.

Comment: I don't know my password !!

Comment: You should probably find out if you want to use it. I'm not a SQL expert, but I would think that you can run the SQL CLI to make a new account, and then give PHP the username and password you just created.

Comment: if i'am change my  : $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''; Something does not happen

Comment: Yes, once you've made your new username and password, you should change those two lines to match.

Comment: Something does not happen !

Comment: If you're using SQL on your local machine, created a new account, put in the username and password, and it's still giving you the same error, I don't know what to do. To quote K&R, "check with a local expert."

Comment: how creat a new acount ? ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was mistaken. You can get more information [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqladmin.html), but apparently what you do is `mysqladmin password` and then it will prompt you for your password, and your username is the name of your account on your operating system. Then you can put that information into the config file and it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the XAMPP package, this should all be configured by that installer and any manual changes might conflict with some behind-the-scenes magic done by the XAMPP package.

That being said, some things make no sense here.

Your `auth_type` is 'cookie' so you're being prompted for a username and password when logging in. The two lines `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'brahim';` and `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';` aren't used at all so you can safely remove them. This isn't directly affecting your ability to log in, but leads to confusion over which password is where and I find it's better to reduce the amount of confusion.

Your problem is the controluser, the lines `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';` and `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';` Comment them out (put a `//` at the beginning of each line) for a few moments to temporarily bypass the advanced configuration features. This should allow you to log in with your usual MySQL username and password.

I see in the comments you mentioned that you don't know your password. By default, MySQL ships with username 'root' and a blank password. Try that. If it doesn't work, you'll have to reset it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18427124/2385479 -- at least on Windows there is a XAMPP provided utility to reset the password. I can't find any reference to where you'd find it on Linux, but look in your XAMPP install folder. Failing that, the [MySQL manual has directions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html) or it's been answered plenty here on Stackoverflow. The generic instructions are to stop mysqld, start it again with `--skip-grant-tables`, manually change the password, then restart mysqld normally -- but you should check out the link because there are specific instructions for most systems.

At this point, you can either use phpMyAdmin as normal or continue to restore the advanced features used by the configuration storage.

Anyway, getting back to your actual question, once you've successfully logged in, check whether there's a `pma` user, and if there is simply change the password. If not, use the SQL statement from the [phpMyAdmin documentation](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage) to create one: `GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON <pma_db>.* TO 'pma'@'localhost'  IDENTIFIED BY 'pmapass';`. Once you know the password, edit `config.inc.php` and plug it in to the 'controlpass' variable, uncomment 'controlpass' and 'controluser' and try again.

Comment: i'm to used Ubuntu , 
my original auth_type is config , i'am to change the auth_type to coockie