# reconfigure phpmyadmin database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Recently being the idiot I am, I locked myself out of phpmyadmin on my mac high sierra after changing the password and I've forgotten my password. I've tried everything I can find on google and none of it works. Mostly because I can't access phpmyadmin via anything. For some reason when I log into my root user through terminal, it has no effect on the phpmyadmin (as if it's running a different mysql).

I am planning to reinstall or wipe my phpmyadmin. How would I go about doing that? I'm using xampp and I've tried reinstalling it.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get back Lost phpMyAdmin Password, XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511444/how-to-get-back-lost-phpmyadmin-password-xampp)

Comment: I am looking for a mac equivalent of 'sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin'

Comment: @GMB I don't know my password. Also I am wondering how I would go about uninstalling and reinstalling

Comment: Check out the answer by Ricardo Parker : seems like you don't need to reinstall

Comment: @GMB I've looked at his solution. phpmyadmin.exe does not exist on mac. I've located the mac version of the file (maybe) and it says its a binary file and doesn't take commands

Comment: ah ok, my bad ! I retracted my vote for duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be exact, you are not locked out of phpMyAdmin but of MySQL. phpMyAdmin is a web interface to MySQL. This is how you can reset your MySQL root password: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html.

The principle is that you will stop your MySQL server and restart it without any security. At this point you'll be able to log in via the "mysql" command line utility and set a password for the root user.