# Reset Root User Permissions on XAMPP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I accidentally deleted all global permission for root:localhost and root:127.0.0.1

How do I reset it? I'm using Windows as an OS.

Comment: [this shoudl point you in the right direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070501/regaining-access-to-lost-mysql-password-for-phpmyadmin-on-wamp/29073563#29073563) its aimed at WAMPServer but the process is the same

Comment: Please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046977/xampp-permissions-on-mac-os-x Hope this helps!

Comment: While neither of them have accepted answers, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24566453/resetting-mysql-root-password-with-xampp-on-localhost and https://stackoverflow.com/a/18427124/2385479 seem to answer this. Specifically, the second one references `C:\xampp\mysql\resetroot.bat` for this purpose.