# mysql> use mysql; but ... ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user '' @ 'localhost' to database 'mysql'

Tags: mysql, database, access-denied, mysql-select-db, mysql-error-1044

Using `mysql.exe`, I enter the command `mysql> use mysql;` but there is an error:

> ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user '' @ 'localhost' to database 'mysql'

- What does this mean?
- How so I can access a mysql database?
- The most important thing is that I want to reset password mysql database, but an error occurs when I enter the command: `mysql> use mysql;`.

Comment: `user ''@'localhost'` implies you connected anonymously, which likely means unprivileged. If you want to modify the `mysql` database you must connect with a privileged user (and directly writing to `mysql.user` is probably not a good idea - better to use `SET PASSWORD` instead https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-password.html)

Comment: please disable any firewalls first, antivirus program or windows may be blocking it

Comment: yes I had to disable antivirus and firewall, but still can not enter the command mysql> use mysql;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

thanks all, finally I found this 
[reset root password with wrong mysql config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124447/)…
 and it works well for me :)

-Go to your xampp\mysql\bin\ folder
-Edit my.ini and insert **skip-grant-tables** below **[mysqld]**
-Restart MySQL
-Set new password for your root user by running **UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('new_password') WHERE User='root'** in phpMyAdmin in the mysql database (or just leave it like this if MySQL cannot be accessed from remote hosts)

AndreKR

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Password' in 'field list'

Answer (score 2):

Grant all privileges to the user first ,

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: thank you for your replay Maku. but what should I do for this? I mean what commands should I use? sorry I'm a beginner

Comment: mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION; 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: what is the password of your mysql?

Comment: I do not sure how many times I changed the password and what I managed to replace / reset the password. whether password  can be reset directly ? But when I'm looking for a way to reset it that I found the following commands: use mysql;
UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD("password") WHERE User='root';
flush privileges;
quit

Comment: Just set your password to none, 
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('');, less hassle for development and execute grant command again

Comment: but to enter the command "use mysql;" absolutely can not. (I mean i just want toreset / replace the root mysql password.

Comment: i tried... mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('');
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'

Comment: is "mysql" a database?

Comment: simple advise,  you can install wamp and sqlyog , this will lessen the burden, no need to use command line.

Comment: I use xampp. that's what I do not understand, but not mysql database that I use. to reinstall xampp, I worry about losing the database, because the fault is I do not backup the database before. while I can not log into phpmyadmin also to backup the database :(

Comment: owww you forgot the password maybe :O

Comment: thanks a lot maku, finally I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124447/reset-root-password-with-wrong-mysql-config and it works well for me :)

Comment: @yuri90 glad you got it now, happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'john'@'localhost' to database 'mysql'

When I tried to select [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/system-schema.html) database(schema) by login with the user `john` as shown below:

```
use mysql
```

So, I gave all privileges on all the tables in `mysql` database(schema) (`mysql.*`) to the user `john` with [GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) by login with the user `root` as shown below, then I could solve the error:

```sql
GRANT ALL ON mysql.* TO 'john'@'localhost';
```

Or:

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mysql.* TO 'john'@'localhost';
```

Answer (score -1):

Open MySQL interface (phpMyadmin) through browser then

1. click Users
2. check users with  grant options if it is  no then follow below steps
3. click->edit privileges (if user with 'no' grant option)
4. then select (global privileges) mark check all
5. continue these steps to all users