# ERROR 1044 (42000) : Access denied for user ' '@localhost to database

Tags: mysql

Having trouble logging in and accessing my database. Currently using Windows 10 EasyPHP 13.1

I tried logging into my database. Using

```
          "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP 13.1\binaries\mysql\bin\mysql.exe" -u  jim -p;
```

An error message appeared saying 
     WARNING: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure
      ERROR 1045 (28000): Access Denied for user 'jim'@'localhost' (using password: YES).
 Then I tried

```
            "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP 13.1\binaries\mysql\bin\mysql.exe" -u  jim;
```

This logged me in. However, I still cannot access the database. 
Whenever I type the following command.

```
 USE publications;
```

I get the error

```
ERROR 1044 (42000) : Access denied for user  ' '@localhost to database 'publications'
```

I have even tried the following

```
  GRANT ALL ON publications.* TO 'jim' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypasswd';
```

and

```
  GRANT ALL ON publications.* TO 'jim'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypasswd';
```

and

```
     GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'jim'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

as recommended at [mysql> use mysql; but ... ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user '' @ 'localhost' to database 'mysql'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30250758/mysql-use-mysql-but-error-1044-42000-access-denied-for-user-local)

Even Logging in as a -u root won't let me access the database. I'm at a loss as to what the problem might be. Any ideas?

Comment: Everything you've done appears correct. The curious part is the error which identifies you as `' '@localhost` rather than `'jim'@localhost` suggesting something is wrong with either your mysql client or server. Perhaps get a mysql client from a different vendor?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'jim'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypasswd';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: I logged in with "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP 13.1\binaries\mysql\bin\mysql.exe" -u  jim; Then typed in what you recommended. Then got the following output "ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ' '@'localhost' to database 'publications' " and another "ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied;  you need (at least one of) the RELOAD privileges for this operation"

Comment: may be use jim have not enough privileges. can you use "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP 13.1\binaries\mysql\bin\mysql.exe" -u root?

Comment: I am able to log in with -u root, but cannot access the database when I use the USE publications; command. I still get the ERROR 1044 message.

Comment: not quite sure now. I updated the post. pls try gain.

Comment: Thanks anyway. Still getting an error message. Tried to log in with -u jim and -u root, with the recommended command. Got the following message ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '  '@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: I'm even having trouble creating another database with the -u root user. Getting the same error ERROR 1044.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP 13.1\binaries\mysql\bin\mysql.exe" -ujim
```

Notice i remove spaces between -u and jim

Comment: I was able to log in, about still cannot access the database when using the USE publications; command. I still get ERROR 1044.